# Как загрузить .dll в visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, импорт

Нужно написать глобальный хук на клавиатуру и мышь. Создал проект dll, собрал. В исполняемом проекта в свойствах: `Linker->Advanced->Import Library` прописал абсолютный путь(скопировал из файловой системы) к .dll файлу полученному в результате сборки.

Далее такой код `dllKeyboard = LoadLibraryA("MouseAndKeyboard.dll");` кидает ошибку 126 - Указанный модуль не может быть найден. Что делать?

Comment: я бы написал как минимум так `LoadLibrary(L"MouseAndKeyboard.dll")`

Answer (score 1):

"Linker->Advanced->Import Library" - настройка студии. К путям поиска DLL, которые используются при вызове `LoadLibrary()`, эта настройка отношения не имеет. Указание полного пути к DLL при загрузке либы определенно должно решить вашу проблему.

Comment: Не помогло - та же ошибка, всё же я предполагаю, что настройка studio имеет некоторое отношение. Брал пример с интернета, автор утверждал, что у него работает) http://www.forum.mista.ru/topic.php?id=340810

Comment: @Nikita не имеет настройка студии никакого отношения к путям загрузки, кто бы что ни говорил. Вы в пути слэши экранировали (\\\)?

Comment: Да, экранировал. Папки которые состояли из двух слов пробовал \"\" и без ковычек.